# Android UiDevice getDisplayHeight() returns wrong value

Tags: android-espresso, android-uiautomator

I'm trying to do some UI test on my app and I wanna get the display dimensions, I used the following snippet on the test case on a **PIXEL 3** emulator

```
UiDevice device = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
int displayHeight = device.getDisplayHeight(); // retunrs 2028
int displayWidth = device.getDisplayWidth(); // returns 1080

return String.format("%sx%s", displayWidth, displayHeight); // returns ("1080x2028")
```

However, I use the traditional `DisplayMetrics` way in my production code to get the screen dimensions as follow:

```
private static DisplayMetrics getDisplayMetrics(Context context) {
        Display defaultDisplay = ((WindowManager) context.getSystemService(Context
                .WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
            defaultDisplay.getRealMetrics(displayMetrics);
        }
        return displayMetrics;
    }

    public static String getScreenSize(Context context) {
        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getDisplayMetrics(context);
        int displayHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels; // retunrs 2160
        int displayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels; // returns 1080
        return String.format("%sx%s", displayWidth, displayHeight); // returns ("1080x2160")
    }
```

I got `2028` pixel for the hieght using `UiDevice instance` and `2160` using the display metrics!!
Does anyone have an explanation for why the `UiDevice` instance returns different screen height?

Answer (score 0):

You should use https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice.html#getdisplaysizedp if you want to obtain the actual size of the screen, rather than adjusted per system decorations (like status bar).